# pymysql getting access denied, while mysql-client works

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I have some python code that looks like this:

```
print('mysql -u {} -h {} -p{} {}'.format(
                                         secrets['username'], 
                                         secrets['host'], 
                                         secrets['password'], 
                                         secrets['dbname']
                                        )
      )

con = pymysql.connect(host=secrets['host'], 
                      user=secrets['username'], 
                      password=secrets['password'], 
                      db=secrets['dbname'])
```

The connection with pymysql fails, it returns

```
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (1045, u"Access denied for user 'my_user'@'client_ip' (using password: YES)")
```

If I copy and run the print statement to connect, it connects right away without any issues:

```
root@host:/tmp# mysql -u my_user -h my_host -pmy_pw mydb
```

How can this be? They are both using the exact same credentials and I'm executing both of them on the same machine, it's just different clients.

Comment: Your `user` may not have access to access the database through external connectors.

Comment: External connector as in another client than the regular mysql-client? Is that a setting?

Comment: Can i try logging into `mysql client` from shell with normal user other than `root`